# How well supported is the Nexus 4 by Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Is the Nexus 4 supported on same the level as the Aquaris E4.5 (is there HERE maps or other turn-by-turn navigation; Nearby scope)? Is there possibility that they will stop supporting Nexus suddenly in a year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Nexus 4 **does** have HERE.
- Nexus 4 does **not** have all the scopes that BQ ships with.
- There is a real risk that Nexus 4 official updates will stop in the future.  It is not a shipped product that has paying customers.  It's just a developer reference device.  And those change.
- Nexus 4 is showing its age.  You can't get it direct from Google anymore.  And it's performance is adequate but not impressive.  For example, Cut the Rope does not run in a playable fashion on a Nexus 4, but it does on the BQ device.